# Getting unique entries from a columns generated by matching regexp in SQL

Tags: mysql, regex, grep

I have a table which i am using to query and getting its one column which matches regular expression which is `(\/.+\/\?)`.

Content of the resulted column is like:
`/Anything here/?`
Example output:

```
\abc\cdf\?....
\ab\?....
\abc\cdf\?....
\sb\?....
```

where `'....'` can be anything

Desired result i want is unique values before `\?` such that rows with duplicate regexp matched content are shown once only like here (`\abc\cdf\?....` showing twice instead of onece)

```
\abc\cdf\?....
\ab\?....
\sb\?....
```

OR

```
\abc\cdf\?
\ab\?
\sb\?
```

I have looked very much but couldn't find anything there is regexp_substr in oracle but that is not working in SQL.

Please if someone could help me with the sql query that would be awesome.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everything before the last `\`, then you can use `substring_index()` and some string manipulation:

```
select substring_index(col, '\\',
                       length(col) - length(replace(col, '\\', ''))
                      ) as firstpart,
       count(*)
from table t
group by substring_index(col, '\\',
                         length(col) - length(replace(col, '\\', ''))
                        );
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my use case just by slight modifications.